# stick footer to the bottom

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I know this is a much discussed topic. but I'm still not really figuring out what I need even when readed a lotof related posts.

I have the problem where a position absolute div doesnt stick to the footer. I have a one page website.

Here is a simplified code of my website:

HTMl:

```
    <div id="e1">hi</div>
    <div id="e2">hi</div>
    <div id="e3">
    <div id="footer">My beautifull footer thingy</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {

margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width:100%;
height:100%;
```

}

```
    #e1 {height:100%; width:100%; background:#ff9000; }
    #e2 {height:100%; width:100%; background:#000;}
    #e3 {height:100%; width:100%; background:#ff9000;}

#footer {
text-align:center;
line-height:80px;
height:300px;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
background:#fff;
}
```

[image: what I want]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/4LXLZ/1/

I know one of the solutions is to add

top:300%;
   margin-top: -300px;

But this is not what I want since there is a cms backbone and I cant tell how much pages are active. So I need something that will set itself to his parent (#e3 in this case)

Another solution I tought about was using javascript to change the css after counting how much pages are active.. but I think this would be a temporary solution and it should be way more easy right?

Anyone knows an easy css fix?

Greetings

Comment: Check this website out: http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: well. I know enough of css. I'm just not really getting out of this particulair problem.

Comment: can't you just take your #footer out of #e3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set position relative to eX

```
#e3 {height:100%; width:100%; background:#ff9000; position : relative}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/4LXLZ/5/)

Comment: yeah its working! thanx mate! quite stupid of me! thanx

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple, the footer needs to be position fixed not absolute. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4LXLZ/2/

```
#footer {
  text-align:center;
  line-height:80px;
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: hmm I think you mis understood me. I dont want the footer sticked to the bottom of the window. but to the bottom of #e3

Comment: @Merijndk oh, then only add `position: relative` to #e3

Comment: @Merijndk no, it's not standard, it has to be declared and also you need to have `bottom:0` on that footer. Here's another fiddle update http://jsfiddle.net/4LXLZ/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the foot actually under `#e3`

http://jsfiddle.net/4LXLZ/4/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="e3"></div>
    <div id="footer">My beautifull footer thingy</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no that is not what i was looking for. As I mentioned it a one one page site. the footer is a part of the e3 div which is 100% height and width. I added a image to my post to explain. Also I marked the answare that was right. Thanx for the help anyway! apriciate it!